# Symfony Lexik Translation env prod

Tags: symfony, translation

I have a problem with "Lexik Translation" on symfony.

Production environment (linux server):
Auto cache clear doesn't work
I need to "cache:clear" manually for the changes to be made

My PC (Windows)
Everything is fine here (Production environment)

I tried this :
adding APCU & OPCACHE
adding delay on auto cache

I'm stuck on this topic, can you help me ?

Comment: Hello everyone sorry

Comment: In composer.json, your package is in `require` or `require-dev` section ?
Check too if package is in `vendor\` directory

Comment: thanks for your response but it's already the case,  no more idea ?  :)

Comment: Can you add the error you got when you try to purge cache ? or anything who can help us to understand :) ?